# Gridsystem from BS3 not working propably in Joomla!

Tags: joomla-3.4, bootstrap

I wrote a realy basic Joomla template.

I added the bootstrapcore in the index.php with:

```
JHtml::_('bootstrap.loadCss', true, $this->direction);
```

I want to have 3 grids after my heading:

```
<div class="container">
    <h1>heading</h1>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                1
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                2
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                3
            </div>
        </div>
    <jdoc:include type="component" />
</div>
```

Somehow this is not displayed the right way:

[image: output]

I work with Joomla 3.4.6

Did i miss something to include?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax in the code above is for Bootstrap 3, but Joomla uses Bootstrap 2.
BS 2 uses `span4` instad of `col-sm-4`

[Read Here](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/scaffolding.html#gridSystem)

Comment: Yes I forgot that. So all you will have to do is to not load the default Bootstrap and load Bootstrap 3.x. You can use a external CDN that provides the Bootstrap files to do that. That would fix your issue.

Answer (score 0):

The first I would do is check the source (check inside the ) to see if Bootstrap is included since your syntax looks correct.

Comment: I'm not absolutely sure what you mean... if I have a view at the rendered sourcecode there is a link to the `bootstrap.min.css`, `bootstrap-responsive.min.css` & `bootstrap-extended.css`